# Using forwardInvocation with subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nsobject

I have class A and class B where B is a subclass of A.  Both A and B are moderately expensive to create but A and B are very similar.  Only a few fields on B are different than on A.  I have an instance of A that I need to turn into an instance of B.  My thought was to try to use forwardInvocation.  B maintains a reference to A and forwards all invocations to A except for the few methods that B has of its own.  On B, I've implemented forwardInvocation:

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {

}
```

But it doesn't appear to be getting called.  I've also implemented respondsToSelector: and methodSignatureForSelector: but they don't seem to be getting called either.  Does something different happen for subclasses?

Comment: Did you return NO in respondsToSelector?

Comment: respondsToSelector isn't getting called.  But I do return NO for any selectors I want to be forwarded.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the structure of A and B. Also, how are these methods being called and what exactly are you trying to accomplish? There may be another way to accomplish what you need without selector forwarding.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  forwardInvocation (and the like) are only called to give the object a chance to handle the message if it doesn't already handle it.  It doesn't bypass the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @ChrimsonChris, A contains mostly properties but the properties are expensive to iterate over and set on a new instance, especially when I only need to change a couple of them.  Essentially what I want is to create a copy of A with a few properties changed without having to iterate over all of A's properties.  Hence, B maintains a reference to A and forwards most invocations to it.

Comment: You haven't really explained _why_ you need to create B. Do you need different methods? Different properties? Have you looked into using categories instead? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/programmingwithobjectivec/customizingexistingclasses/customizingexistingclasses.html

Comment: Even what you really need to create is a subclass, you can still use COW to prevent copying everything.

Comment: Without getting too much into it, let's say that A is an immutable representation of a numbered set of objects.  A represents all that is common to the entire set of these objects.  However, there are a couple of properties (also immutable) that are unique to each object.  So essentially I need a copy of A to back each object.  I'm trying to avoid this by having B which forwards most invocations to A except for the few properties that differ.  Therefore, I have only one A and a bunch of Bs which should be cheap to create.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Maxthon Chan, can you explain how that works?  I'm assuming COW is copy-on-write?  I don't see how that helps here.

Comment: Sounds like you could have a number of B's that hold a reference to a common A. I don't see the need for inheritance here. You _could_ have both B and A implement the same protocol. B would then call methods on A when appropriate.

Comment: A and B already implement the same protocol.  I should have mentioned that what I'm trying to avoid is having to manually implement a list of methods on B that just pass through to A.  Everytime someone adds a new method to A they'll have to remember to add it to B.  I was hoping I could do something more automatic.

Comment: The simplest way is that make the B object hold an weak reference to the A object it is created from, and when properties and functions are accessed, if a value is not set, ask the A object it is generated from for the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my original question is as follows:

forwardInvocation is only invoked when an object is sent a message for which it has no corresponding method.  In the case of subclassing, obviously if the superclass has a corresponding method, forwardInvocation will not get called.  The key here, then, is to make my "proxy" object not be a subclass.

What I actually would like is for my "proxy" object to truly be a subclass object.  I want to be able to use forwardInvocation but I would also like the benefit of having methods that do this:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithSelf {
    [someObject doSomethingWith:self];
}
```

and have self be the proxy object.